# Is it a good practise if I make classes for common css style settings and assign them to html elements?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

style.css

```
.background-cover{background-size:cover; background-position:center;}
.op-1{opacity:0.1;}
.border-3-solid{border-width:3px; border-color: solid;}
.border-black{border-color:#000;}
.full-width{width:100%;}
```

index.html

```
    <div class="full-width background-cover op-1 border-3-solid 
border-black" style="background-image:url('imageurl.png')"></div>
```

Is using more number of classes per element can be an issue in a long time?
Should I create more general utility classes like these or just defined styles for each element and use lesser classes?

Comment: If you are not going to reuse these class in several elements, it's a terrible practice

Comment: You should consider to choose class names based on what things are and not on how things should be displayed. So you have classes like "article", "comment", "user", "rating" instead of "border-3-solid", "green", "half-width"...

Comment: I'm putting this as a comment because the question is kind of subjective, but having loads of classes makes it a bit confusing. A better option similar to what you are trying to achieve is using inheritance in CSS preprocessors like SASS. E.g. if you are going to use the exact same typography several times with the only difference being colour, you could use inheritance to add on to classes. Read more here: http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using more number of classes can be cumbersome to manage if you're having a large project. What good is that you should group commonly used stylings and properties into a class and later use them on your HTML page, this way your application will have a solid appearance and you can easily modify/edit them in future. In this way, you can also define additional paddings and other small changes to your elements on style sheet by calling them with their id, So your code looks cleaner and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice if you want to be UI Designer.

> less you code more you learn.

The classes are defined as sets of html page designs which you may want to change quick in future or may be an other team mate wants to deal with that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Adding More classes makes your page execution time slow.so use less classes 
    and group commonly used stylings and properties into a class.